# xPages repeat control onmouseover

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have a repeat control that contains simple checkBox and computed field (doesn't really matter), like this:

         `[ ] text1
         [x] text2
         [ ] text3
         [x] text4
         [x] text5`

I want to show additional clickable icon next the current item/row when you hover a mouse pointer over it

         `[ ] text1
    (*)  [x] text2
         [ ] text3
         [x] text4
         [x] text5`

Is that possible?
Thanks

P.S. I need to show that icon regardless of where the mouse cursor (checkbox or text field). I want to show it for the current row (when mouse cursor somewhere within current row)

Comment: maybe I need to save row index in some scope variable... Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with an easy CSS trick. As an example, take the following repeat control:

```
<xp:table>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label
                value="Some Header"
                id="label1">
            </xp:label>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:repeat
        id="repeat1"
        rows="30"
        var="textValue"
        indexVar="index">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5"] }]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:tr
            styleClass="magicRow">
            <xp:td>
                <xp:button
                    value="x"
                    id="button1"
                    styleClass="magicButton">
                </xp:button>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:checkBox
                    text=""
                    id="checkBox1">
                </xp:checkBox>
                <xp:text
                    escape="true"
                    id="computedField1"
                    value="#{textValue}">
                </xp:text>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:table>
```

We have used the repeat control within a table, so it repeats row elements 5 times. Now we will use the following CSS to hide the magic button and show it only when mouse pointer is over the row:

```
tr.magicRow .magicButton { visibility:hidden; } 
tr.magicRow:hover .magicButton { visibility:visible; }
```

`:hover` is a useful [CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp).

Comment: this is it.. This works great.. Thank you Mr. Basegmez

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's possible.  I don't have a code example handy as I'm not great with Client Side JavaScript but I have to think you can, with dojo or jQuery, attach an event to the on hover or maybe even "onmouseout" of  and in that event you could use the dojo/jquery to add/remove css to your button.